# Envers - Select entities that have been edited

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to implement a feature to synchronize an Android app with the server.

At synchronization time, the app in android logs in and says when it was your last sync (this is just theory for now).

The question is, the server needs to select all entities that have changed since the date reported, filtering by the customer, and answer them (in json) to the app;

An alternative would be to create a column "lastUpdate" in each entity.
However, the web system already uses Hibernate Envers. Entities are annotated with `@audited`.

**How can I select all entities that have changed since a date, using the `revinfo` table?**
Remembering that I don't need the history of the entity. Just need to know what has changed. Only the latest version will be sent to the android app.
How do I get an entity which has been modified several times appears only once during the upgrade?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to keep such application logic separate from the revinfo table, on the principle of Separation of Concern.

Not quite sure about the specifics of your case, but a join table with revision ids and booleans (or dates) is a low cost way of tracking this activity while leaving your Envers audit data in an clean state. After all, your business logic may change and use cases may multiply, but the auditing of changes to your entities is likely to remain the same.